# is growth of x+sin(x) same as x?

Tags: calculus

$$\begin{align}
{\lim_{x\to +\infty}  \frac{x+\sin(x)}{x}}
\end{align}$$

so if we use L'Hospital's Rule we get

$$\begin{align}
{\lim_{x\to +\infty} 1+\cos(x)}
\end{align}$$

so the answer is a constant between $0$ and $2$. 
but the $0$ is kind of a problem here since 
if the answer to the limit is $0$ then it means $x$ grows faster than $x+\sin(x)$
but if the answer to the function is a finite positive number (not necessarily constant) 
then the two functions have same growth speed !

can't we just not take into account the points where $1+\cos(x)=0$ since they are a countable set as apposed to other points which are uncountable and majority of our function consists of them! and say the two functions have the same growth speed.

Comment: $x+sin(x) \in \Theta (x)$ which means that the growth is the same.

Comment: you cant' use the Hospital rule because $$\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac{(x+\sin x)'}{x'}=\lim_{x\to\infty }1+\cos x$$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the  L'Hospital rule. The rule states that if $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) = \infty$$
**AND IF** the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
exists or is $\infty$, then the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ also exists and
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

In your case, the second demand is not met, so you cannot use L'Hospital to solve the problem.

That does not mean, however, that the limit of $\frac{x+\sin x}{x}$ does not exits. To find this limit, let me start:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+\sin x}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}1+\frac{\sin x}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} 1 + \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac{x+\sin x}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)=1$$
because $$\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac{\sin x}{x}=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact, that
\begin{align}
\frac12 x \leq x +\sin(x) \leq 2 x
\end{align} 
for $x>2$.  This is exactly the definition of  Big-$\Theta$ , which means, that $x+\sin(x)$ is bounded by $x$ from above and below. Thus they grow with the same rate.

Answer (score 0):

One more way: $-1<\sin x <1$, so the fraction is bounded by 
$$
1-\frac{1}{x}<\frac{x-1}{x} < \frac{x - \sin x}{x}<\frac{x+1}{x}<1+ \frac{1}{x}
$$
Both upper and lower bounds are $\Theta(1)$, so $\frac{x+\sin x }{x} = \Theta(1)$